# верстка сайта под мобильное устройство

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

В так называемой ПК версии (не знаю, как правильно сказать подругому) все выглядит хорошо, но вот когда просматриваю сайт на андроиде или же через гуглхром на ПК с применением toggle device mod, то вижу жуть жуткую. Пытался прописать обычное свойство

```
<pre><code>font-size:12px;</code></pre>
```

но все равно не то, что надо. Ссылка на сайт. прошу подтолкнуть в нужном направлении.

Черным выделен пример некорректности. и там, и там задан размер 12px
[image: несоответствие размеров]

Comment: забыл указать ссылку на сайт. [ссылка](http://economics.opu.ua/)

Comment: адрес той самой страницы со скрина можно?

Comment: @mix http://economics.opu.ua/authors-portal

Comment: как вариант, иногда помогает поочередное отключение всех стилей через тот же отладчик, которые могут влиять на элемент. так можно вычислить, когда начинается "неожиданное" поведение элемента

Answer (score 1):

Если надо что бы сайт был под мобильные устройства, то попробуй в head добавить:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

и прочитай про [медиа-запросы](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media)

а лучше посмотри видео на [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1i0d8JxreQ)

Comment: К сожалению человек, который просил сделать сайт, вопросил удалить медиа верстку с шаблона wordpress

Comment: простите, тогда я не очень понимаю в чем проблема ( можете уточнить :?

Answer (score 0):

решением будет добавление css свойствa

```
.name_author table a {
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

Тогда ссылки внутри таблицы и ссылки на автора будут одинакового размера.

Пока пробовал найти решение, наткнулся на то, что "искажает" размер "а" именно таблица. При чём, если "а" добавить `display: inline-block`, то `font-size: 32px` нужно делать, чтобы выровнять до оригинала (и это уже будет 2 решение данного вопроса). Наверное, где-то с % ошибка.